# How do I use casperjs to access the url and invoke the javascript/content?

Tags: javascript, casperjs

A test site uses javascript (the decrypt functions) to generate the output content. A simple test casperjs script was created to get the site content.

The target url is:

```
http://udel.bncollege.com/webapp/wcs/stores/servlet/TBListView?storeId=37554&termMapping=Y&catalogId=10001&langId=-1&courseXml=%3C%3Fxml+version%3D%221.0%22%3F%3E%3Ctextbookorder%3E%3Cschool+id%3D%22289%22+%2F%3E%3Ccourses%3E%3Ccourse+num%3D%22200%22+dept%3D%22ACCT%22+sect%3D%22010%22+term%3D%222163%22%2F%3E%3C%2Fcourses%3E%3C%2Ftextbookorder%3E
```

If one enters the URL directly into a browser, the required content is displayed if the JScript is enabled. Without JScript enabled the displayed content is the encrypted "content".

The goal is to invoke the underlying JScript, to then process the encrypted content, displaying the generated content.

As far as I can tell, running the test casperjs script should process the underlying javascript on the page.

Any thoughts on what is missing???

The test code sample is:

```
/*
*
*    udel.js:        test to take input url
*
*    udel.js 
*
*
*/
var utils = require('utils');
var casper = require('casper').create({
    verbose: true,
    logLevel: 'error',
    pageSettings: {
      loadImages: false,
      loadPlugins: true,
      userAgent: 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.2; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/29.0.1547.2 Safari/537.36'
  }
  });

casper.start('http://udel.bncollege.com/webapp/wcs/stores/servlet
/TBListView?storeId=37554&termMapping=Y&catalogId=10001&langId=-1
&courseXml=%3C%3Fxml+version%3D%221.0%22%3F%3E%3Ctextbookorder
%3E%3Cschool+id%3D%22289%22+%2F%3E%3Ccourses%3E%3Ccourse
+num%3D%22200%22+dept%3D%22ACCT%22+sect%3D%22010%22
+term%3D%222163%22%2F%3E%3C%2Fcourses%3E%3C%2Ftextbookorder%3E'
, function() {
        this.echo(this.page.content);
});

casper.run();
```

Thoughts on what's missing??

Thanks

Comment: Why do you think that PhantomJS supports JScript?

Comment: Hi Artjom.  The whole purpose of phantomJS/CasperJS, is to run a headless browser, which essentially runs the underlying JScript of a site, in the same manner as a normal browser

Comment: No, PhantomJS runs JavaScript, but I don't think it has (full) JScript support.

Comment: It does. There are plenty of others using py/phantomJS to do headless browser/test apps -- ie, able to implement the underlying javascript from different javascript libs

Comment: Yes, but you've mentioned [JScript](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JScript) which is not the same as JavaScript. Which is it then?